# Parse JSON file with no objects Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing, struct, codable

I am trying to parse the following JSON file with Swift. I am lost on how to parse a file with no objects so any help would be great. Below is the sample JSON

```
[
    "sleeping bag",
    "Arabian camel, dromedary, Camelus dromedarius",
    "water"
]
```

The code I have setup to decode the file is below

```
struct ItemsStruct: Codable {
    let item: String
}

public extension Decodable{
    static func fromFile<T : Decodable>(_ filename : String, class : T.Type)->T?{
        let fileparts = filename.split(separator: ".")
        guard fileparts.count == 2 else{
            return nil
        }
        guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: String(fileparts[0]), withExtension: String(fileparts[1])),
            let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: path),
            let _struct = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else{
                return nil
        }
        return _struct
    }
}

guard let items = ItemsStruct.fromFile("objects.json", class: [ItemsStruct].self) else {return}
        for item in items{
            print(item)
        }
```

I know that I shouldnt have "let item: String" but I'm not sure what to put in the struct since there are no objects.

Do I need different JSON data?

Comment: There is one object, an array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an array of `String`

```
guard let items = [String].fromFile("objects.json", class: [String].self) else {return}
for item in items{
    print(item)
}
```

The syntax is pretty weird by the way. And you should make the method `throw` to hand over all possible errors rather than returning an optional and ignoring all errors.